# Iterate through a struct with an embedded struct

Tags: go, struct, reflection, embedding, go-reflect

I have several structs that are receiving data. All structs shall include some of the same data, which have been embedded with the `HeaderData` struct. The data is not filled at the same time, and I need a function to check if all the fields have received a value (is not an empty string).

I tried to solve this with reflect. The problem is that reflect will consider the `HeaderData` to be one field. This means that it will always be a non-empty string, although it may include empty fields. So I believe that I need a way to check that struct separately.

I tried to access it with `anyStruct.HeaderData`, but that is not working since “{} is interface with no methods”.

Is there any other way to access the `HeaderData` so that this works?

Or can I in some way specify in the `dataReady` that the input must have the field `HeaderData`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type HeaderData struct {
    Param1  string
    Param2  string
}

type Data1 struct {
    HeaderData 
    Param3  string
    Param4  string
}

type Data2 struct {
    HeaderData 
    Param3  string
    Param5  string
}

func dataReady(anyStruct interface{}) bool {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(anyStruct)
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        // fmt.Println(v.Field(i).Interface())
        if v.Field(i).Interface() == "" {
            return false
        }
    }


    // v1 := reflect.ValueOf(anyStruct.HeaderData)
    // Not working:
    // anyStruct.HeaderData undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)

    return true
}

func main() {
    d1 := Data1{HeaderData: HeaderData{Param1: "ABC", Param2: "DEF"}, Param3: "GHI", Param4: "JKL"}
    d2 := Data2{HeaderData: HeaderData{Param1: "ABC", Param2: "DEF"}}
    d3 := Data2{HeaderData: HeaderData{Param1: "ABC"}, Param3: "GHI", Param5: "JKL"}
    d4 := Data2{Param3: "GHI", Param5: "JKL"}
    fmt.Println("d1Ready: ", dataReady(d1))     //Returns true, which is correct
    fmt.Println("d2Ready: ", dataReady(d2))     //Returns false, which is correct
    fmt.Println("d3Ready: ", dataReady(d3))     //Returns true but should return false
    fmt.Println("d4Ready: ", dataReady(d4))     //Returns true but should return false
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Nvdmi4u4q9N)

Comment: Why do you need reflect for this? Have a method/function for checking the fields of `HeaderData` and methods/unctions for those `DataN` structs; the methods/functions on the latter would call to the method/function which would check the fields of the HeaderData _field_ in them (the fact it's embedded does not preclude accessing it via the name of its type).

Comment: You might think this is "too much code" but in exchange it's more understandable (and way more faster).

Comment: @kostix That is an option, and maybe I should do it like that. But as you mention it will be more code, I will need one function per struct. Also If there is a change in a struct I will have to update the function. So I thought it would be nice if I had a more generic way of checking this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try a little interface to do the same thing and i think that this would be a lot more readable.

https://play.golang.org/p/H4lh91RMd6C

```
package main

import (
     "fmt"
)

 type(

     FieldCheck interface {
         Check() (b bool)
     }

     HeaderData struct {
         Param1  string
         Param2  string
     }

    Data1 struct {
         HeaderData
         Param3  string
         Param4  string
     }

     Data2 struct {
         HeaderData
         Param3  string
         Param5  string
     }
  )

func(h *HeaderData) Check() (b bool) {
     if h.Param1 == "" || h.Param2 == "" {
         return false
     }
     return true
}

func(d *Data1) Check() (b bool) {
     if (d.Param3 == "" || d.Param4 == "" || ! d.HeaderData.Check()) {
         return false
     }
     return true
}

func(d *Data2) Check() (b bool) {
     if (d.Param3 == "" || d.Param5 == "" || ! d.HeaderData.Check()) {
         return false
     }
     return true
 }


func main() {

    d := []FieldCheck{
         &Data1{HeaderData: HeaderData{Param1: "ABC", Param2: "DEF"}, Param3: 
"GHI", Param4: "JKL"},
        &Data2{HeaderData: HeaderData{Param1: "ABC", Param2: "DEF"}},
        &Data2{HeaderData: HeaderData{Param1: "ABC"}, Param3: "GHI", Param5: 
"JKL"},
        &Data2{Param3: "GHI", Param5: "JKL"},
    }

    for _, num := range d {
        fmt.Println(num.Check())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, it seem like that is the way to go. The drawback is that if a field is added to a struct, the Check method must also be updated with the new field. But hopefully the structs will be quite stable :-)

Comment: I did it like that for simplicity, you can loop the fields at each level of the struct and therefore not have do this. you could also have a type assertion to make it a little more dynamic.

Comment: That’s true. Thanks :-)